# Using assignment operator overloading to return jobject from class

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, java-native-interface, assignment-operator

I am using the JNI invocation API and I would like to be able to perform the following assignment in my main() function:

```
jobject Myjobject = MyClassInstance;
```

Where MyClassInstance is an object instance of MyClass.

MyClass.h:

```
// DEFINE OVERLOADED = OPERATOR //
    jobject operator= (const MyClass &);
```

MyClass.cpp:

```
jobject MyClass::operator =(const MyClass & MyInstance)
{
    return MyInstance.jobjectMember;
}
```

Where jobjectMember is a private jobject member of MyClass.

However, I keep getting the following error during compilation:

> error: cannot convert ‘MyClass’ to ‘jobject {aka _jobject*}’ in
>   assignment

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `jobject Myjobject = MyClassInstance;` this is not an assignment

Comment: btw begin the wrong operator aside, is `Myjobject` of type `MyClass` or of type `jobject` ? If your operator= is a member of `MyClass` you would need `MyObject` as the lhs to call it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order `jobject Myjobject = MyClassInstance;` (which is initialization, not an assignment) to work you need to define a corresponding constructor for `jobject` class.

```
class jobject
{
    public: explicit
    jobject(MyClass const & that) {...}
```

or define conversion operator for `MyClass`

```
  class MyClass 
  {
      public: explicit
      operator jobject const &(void) const
      {
          return this->jobjectMember;
      }

  jobject Myjobject{static_cast<jobject const &>(MyClassInstance)};
```

Comment: Might be worth to mention that `explicit` is not mandatory - without, one can drop the explicit cast. Good idea? Probably a matter of use case... Is there any good discussion about when to prefer one over the other?

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I am relatively new to C++ but the conversion operator is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just explaining *why* your code fails (how to solve: see [VTT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7860670/vtt)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53043305/1312382)):

```
jobject MyClass::operator=(const MyClass& MyInstance)
{
    return MyInstance.jobjectMember;
}
```

This would allow to assign an instance of `MyClass` be assigned *another* instance of – well, `MyClass`:

```
MyClass x, y;
x = y;
```

Now, however, while the code might be legal, it is at least very unusual, I'd rather say it is violating good practice or common conventions: Normally, the assignment operator returns the object being assigned – of correct type and by reference:

```
MyClass& MyClass::operator=(const MyClass& other)
{
    return *this;
}
```

This would allow to do things like these:

```
MyClass x, y, z;
x = y = z;
```

which is what people expect from assignment. Your variant, in contrast, would allow:

```
jobject o;
MyClass x, y;
o = x = y; // ???
```

Additionally, you expect, after assignment, the destination object being the same as the target object (more or less at least), so you'd normally copy the jobject as well:

```
MyClass& MyClass::operator=(MyClass const& other)
{
    jobjectMember = other.jobjectMember;
    return *this;
}
```

Finally: If already writing custom assignment operators, have a look at the [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) and [rule of five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11), they might help you avoid some trouble in the future.